# MongoDB equivalent of SQL "TOP"

Tags: jquery, mongodb, jqgrid

Select Top 10 a, b from users
equivalent sql query in MONGODB

As a part of jqgrid functionality to save the json data and retrieve json data from the DB, I needed this simple SQL query in MONGODB.

Comment: please elabore what you wanted to achieve, what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
.limit()
```

Example:

```
db.things.find().limit(10)
```

Documentation:
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%7B%7Blimit%28%29%7D%7D

As per the comment below, technically, you'd want to sort the collection too, so it would be:

```
db.things.find().sort({someField:1}).limit(10)
```

Comment: add sort() in the chain and it's the answer ;-)

Comment: well... i omitted .sort() due to him not having an 'ORDER BY' in his original sql query ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Short question, short answer: you can achieve this with `sort()` and `limit()`