# Find TOP (1) for each ID in array

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I have a large (60m+) document collection, whereby each ID has many records in time series.  Each record has an IMEI identifier, and I'm looking to select the most recent record for each IMEI in a given `List<Imei>`.

The brute force method is what is currently happening, whereby I create a loop for each IMEI and `yield` out the top most record, then return a complete collection after the loop completes. As such:

```
        List<BsonDocument> documents = new List<BsonDocument>();

        foreach(var config in imeiConfigs)
        {
            var filter = GetImeiFilter(config.IMEI);
            var sort = GetImeiSort();
            var data = _historyCollection.Find(filter).Sort(sort).Limit(1).FirstOrDefault();

            documents.Add(data);
        }
```

The end result is a `List<BsonDocument>` which contains the most recent `BsonDocument` for each `IMEI`, but it's not massively performant. If `imeiConfigs` is too large, the query takes a long time to run and return as the documents are rather large.

Is there a way to select the `TOP 1` for each `IMEI` in a single query, as opposed to brute forcing like I am above?

Comment: That should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13310934/mongodb-equivalent-of-sql-top

Comment: @Rafalsonn taking the `limit(1)` is what I'm already doing above. I'm looking to run a single query to get the top most document for *each IMEI* in a single query, as opposed to looping through and selecting a `limit(1)` on a single IMEI then adding that to a collection.

Comment: What happens in `GetImeiFilter()` and `GetImeiSort()`? What are each results and how are the classes setup? My approach would be to reach the goal with LINQ-to-Object with where and group clauses. If all conditions are explained and maybe some example data was provided sb. could help you to build a fitting query.

Comment: posting sample data (from mongo collection) would help. also mention what indexes you've created.

Answer (score 0):

have tried using the LINQ **Take** function?

```
        List documents = new List();
```

`foreach(var config in imeiConfigs)
    {
        var filter = GetImeiFilter(config.IMEI);
        var sort = GetImeiSort();
        var data = _historyCollection.Find(filter).Sort(sort).Take(1).FirstOrDefault();

        documents.Add(data);
    }`

https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0):

I think bad performance come from "Sort(sort)", because the sorting forces it to go through all the collection.

But perhaps  you can improuve time performance with parallel.

```
List<BsonDocument> documents;

documents =  imeiConfigs.AsParallel().Select((config) =>
{
    var filter = GetImeiFilter(config.IMEI);
    var sort = GetImeiSort();
    var data = _historyCollection.Find(filter).Sort(sort).Limit(1).FirstOrDefault();

    return data;
}).ToList();
```